# Create my own keyboard input layout

Tags: keyboard-layout

I need to create a keyboard layout based on a layout of a Windows program. Many people used this layout but its not available in Ubuntu. Can I do this?

P.S.
Wouldn't it make more sense to organise the keyboard layout by script not language. For instance the Dzongkha language uses the same script as Tibetan and has a much easier layout to learn.

Answer (score 14):

You're probably referring to a layout you created with the **Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator**. Here are a few Linux alternatives:

- http://people.uleth.ca/~daniel.odonnell/Blog/custom-keyboard-in-linuxx11
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=1092145&postcount=1
- http://code.google.com/p/keyboardlayouteditor/

Comment: Great. +1 for the pointers.