# How to Customize the (Phonetic-Arabic) Keyboard Layout?

Tags: keyboard, layout, arabic

uI am a newcomer to the linux world. Been using msoft for 20years or more.  Just moved to Ubuntu since 3 weeks and I am really enjoying it.

I am needing an phonetic keyboard for arabic similar to the one at www.arabic-keyboard.org

This keyboard is not like the arabic keyboard available in ubuntu. It is a customized version.  I would like to know if this is available, or how can I proceed to design one.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be one [feasible](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1654199&highlight=.Xmodmap) way: taking the ubuntu Arabic phonetic layout as a template, and customizing it (as described in the link) to meet your preferences.

Further, see [Create my own keyboard input layout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92751/create-my-own-keyboard-input-layout/92801#92801) and the links cited therein:

> - http://people.uleth.ca/~daniel.odonnell/Blog/custom-keyboard-in-linuxx11
> - http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=1092145&postcount=1
> - http://code.google.com/p/keyboardlayouteditor/

Further, on the idea of porting/converting a Windoze keyboard layout to the Linux world (welcome, btw!), these links might be a good starting point:

- http://blechtog.wordpress.com/2012/05/31/project-linux-to-windows-keyboard-layout-converter/
- https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/keyboard-layouts