# Importing Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator (MKLC) files

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, convert

I have a couple of legacy Windows keyboard layouts for a number of languages that I made 8 years ago on Win7.
They were made with the "Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator" which saves the layouts to .klc files in its own specific binary format and compiles them directly to DLLs.

As I've almost completely switched to Ubuntu now, I'm looking for a good way to port those layouts to Linux.
I've read how the Linux system works here: [What are the steps needed to create new keyboard layout on ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510024/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-create-new-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu), and recreating the layouts manually would be doable but extremely tedious. So I need a tool.

This question was raised more than 5 years ago: [Any tool for importing Microsoft .klc file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580997/any-tool-for-importing-microsoft-klc-file) so it's time to ask it again:

Is there any program out there that converts MKLC files to Linux keyboard layout files?

Comment: The answer (AFAIK) is still no. But maybe you could ask for help on realizing a specific layout since you already know the layout. What tools does Microsoft offer to display the layout?

Comment: If you could make a file that defines the layout, with one line for each key, like `key <AE01> { [        1, exclam,      onesuperior,  exclamdown      ] };`, 'someone' here (me?) could make this into something you can integrate in your system.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that - without burdening anyone else obviously but the offer is appreciated :) I did accidentally find out the Windows files are in fact plain-text, so I'll see if I can map that to the Linux layout spec format.

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to find an xkb to klc converter, I found this repository: https://github.com/alexriss/keyboard-layout-converter

Last commit is from 2016, but I hope it works.